Engineering related TV show (Probably British) aired around 2006-07?
Note: It's not Discovery Channel's "The Big Brain Theory (2013)" Or the "Rough Science". 
Both shows sound pretty similar. The show I'm talking about was aired around 2006-07 (but I'm not sure)
I'm sure that the show was aired on The Direcovery channel or The National Geographic channel.
Two Engineers get new challenges in every episode. The challenges are always hard and sometimes impossible. One guy is good with planning he draws things and make plans. Second guy is very good with the tools.
In one episode they get challenged to find a way to provide electricity to the house located in the middle of nowhere (vast fields, around the mountains)
They both accept the challenge. One dude builds windmill to generate electricity and the other dude use waterfall. They use giant water pipes to transfer water.
That's all I remember about the show.
The Episode I want is very, very similar to this




This sounds like the show Planet Mechanics. In episode 3 they do just as you have described.

from wiki "Planet Mechanics sees two engineers, Dick Strawbridge and Jem Stansfield, travelling in an eco-friendly workshop, previously a horse trailer, to fix the planet's most pressing environmental problems."



Yes! That's it. Thank you so much. You have no idea how long i have been looking for this. How the hell did you find it?

haha. I just enjoy researching things for people.
